# Make doxygen generate link to a class used as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, doxygen

Suppose I have a simple class hierarchy like this:

```
template<class T> class TBase {};

class Param {};

class Derived : TBase<Param> {};
```

Here the `Derived` class is derived from the template `TBase` class specialized with the `Param` class. Doxygen generates the following inheritance diagram for `Derived`:

[image]

And the collaboration diagram looks exactly the same. Doxygen sees that I used `Param` class to construct my `Derived` class. But there is no link for this class from the documentation page of `Derived` class! I can click on rectangles with `TBase<T>` and `TBase<Param>` to get to the page for `TBase` class, but there is no way to get to `Param` class in one click.

Even more, I would like to see something like the following on the collaboration diagram:

[image]

Now it is clear that I use `Param` to construct `Derived`. Is there a way to make doxygen generate such diagrams? Or is there a way to at least make the `<Param>` caption of the arrow clickable?

PS. I used the following doxygen settings:

```
HAVE_DOT               = YES
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES 
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES  
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
```